Remove easing from animated material
So I animated the displacement in my material by animating the location property of the wave texture and it has easing. How do I remove this easing, preferably on the existing animation? I tried looking for it in the graph editor but there's no graph or channel or nothin' for properties in the material.
Edit: to show keyframes for the material node in the timeline, select both the object and the material node in the shader editor (by splitting the view).
